# Semantically correct tag to enclose a forum post

Tags: html

In HTML 5 what's the tag that is supposed to enclose a forum post, being as semantically correct as possible?

- `<div>`
- `<article>`
- `<section>`
- Other?

Comment: Don’t forget, there’s not really any such thing as “correctness” in semantics. Meaning only exists via human beings agreeing about things, so it’s always a bit fuzzy. Good to think about these things though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Working Draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element) an article

> The article  element represents  a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a **forum post**, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `<article>` is best suited, see http://www.alistapart.com/articles/previewofhtml5 for an excellent reference document.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used `<blockquote>` for forum posts and blog comments. But `<article>` seems to be a good option too.

Answer (score -1):

AS other mention above, <article>. But within that article you may want to split it up into sections (in <section>) as long as each section has a natural heading, otherwise don't.

e.g.
<article>
   <section>
      <header><h1>Introduction</h1></header>
      section content goes here

   </section>
   <section>
      <header><h1>Heading 1</h1></header>
      section content goes here

   </section>
   <section>
      <header><h1>Conclusion</h1></header>
      section content goes here

   </section>
</article>

Comment: Huh? What kind of forum has posts that consist of sections with headings and content? I've never encountered a forum whose posts had the structure you suggest here.

Comment: Just because you haven't doesn't mean others haven't. But the answer was moving on from just a simple forum post to show that it was possible to separate the contens if it was so wished.